# Loader issue in react-native-web: Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: react-native, webpack, ts-loader

I'm trying to setup React Native Web App with TypeScript and WebPack. While running the code I'm getting the around 63 errors all in node_modules

**Bug Report**

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js 11:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
|
> export interface EventSubscription {
|   remove(): void;
| }
 @ ../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/SharedEventEmitter.js 18:0-78 20:19-31
 @ ../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/index.js 25:0-69 25:0-69
 @ ../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/analytics/lib/index.js 31:0-35:49 134:38-52 816:15-36 830:24-39
 @ ../src/routes/Navigation.tsx 29:36-79
 @ ../App.tsx 14:37-71
 @ ../index.web.ts 8:30-46
```

**webpack-config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const rootDir = path.join(__dirname, '..');
const webpackEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {
  mode: webpackEnv,
  entry: {
    app: path.join(rootDir, './index.web.ts'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(rootDir, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app-[hash].bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(tsx|ts|jsx|js|mjs)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, './index.html'),
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.web.tsx', '.web.ts', '.tsx', '.ts', '.web.jsx', '.web.js', '.jsx', '.js'],
    alias: Object.assign({
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
    }),
  },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmit": false,
    "strict": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Any help would be most helpful.